# Download Manager Query returns nothing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app users are able to download files, which uses Download Manager. What I want to do is get all the files that are still downloading and check if the one I care about is still downloading, but what happens is it skips the while entirely.

Here is my code:

```
//Check if the file is downloading
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterById(DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Cursor c = dm.query(q);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE)).equals("example-file-name.mp4"){
                file_exists = true;
                holder.download_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.pgb_downloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        }
        c.close();
```

Comment: You jump over the first and there is no second one.

Comment: So the c.moveToNext() gets executed before it enters the while? If so, using a do while will probably fix this, thank you.

Comment: Just delete the line `c.moveToFirst();`.

Comment: @blackapps I have tried commenting it before and the same happens